# "Progress dots" in D3, Wolfram style

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, progress-bar

`Wolfram` (math-related site) has following progress bar (or should I say progress dots):

[image]

You can see it in action [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20987x%5E17-1597x%5E16%2B1).

How would this be implemented in D3?

I wrote this [codepen](http://codepen.io/VividD/pen/aBuDm) in D3, with some different idea:

[image]

Maybe it can serve as a starting point.

Comment: I looks like the Wolfram animation is actually some form of cellular automata. That should be fairly easy to implement in your own code, if someone can figure out what CA it is.

Comment: Good point, thanks. @p.s.w.g Though, given that Wolfram guys have strong math skills, it could some difficult method.

Comment: Are you looking to do a Game of Life kind of thing or simple have circles animate into and out of existence. There are cellular automata examples in D3 for the former and the latter is straightforward if that's all you want to do.

Comment: I am looking for just animation, similar to displayed in the first pic, not any kind of complex game. @Elijah

Comment: @VividD [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is a very popular and widely studied cellular automaton. Googling for "D3 Game of Life" yields a number of tutorials. The Wolfram animation is clearly not the Game of Life, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the circles you've generated to animate in and out of existence, this will work.

I love your best circle generator, but it would be easier if it generated an array of data like the following:

```
[
{x: 14, y: 15, r: 5},
{x: 200, y: 100, r:8}
]
```

With an array like that, you can use transition chaining:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(generatedCircleArray)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 0)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y})
    .transition()
    .delay(function() {return Math.random() * 500})
    .each(animate)

function animate() {
  var circle = d3.select(this);
  (function repeat() {
    circle = circle.transition()
        .attr("r", function(d) {return r})
      .transition()
        .attr("r", 0)
        .each("end", repeat);
  })();
}
```

That's adapted from [this example.](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997)

That should show the circles animate into and out of existence. You can pair that with animating the opacity or varying the opacity to mix it up.